# Why can't Icons.Filled.PlayArrow with tint property change color when IconButton is disabled in Jetapck Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

The Code A displays a preset *Play* icon with default black color when `IconButton` is enabled, and it change gray color automatically when `IconButton` is disabled.

In Code B, I fill in the *Play* icon with blue color, but I find the *Play* icon always displays blue color no matter `IconButton` is enabled or disabled.

How can I make the *Play* icon to display blue color when `IconButton` is enabled, and gray color ( other color ) when `IconButton` is disabled ?

**Code A**

```
IconButton(
        enabled = (mViewMode.playState == EPlayState.PAUSED),
        onClick = {  }
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.PlayArrow , null, modifier = iconModifier )
    }
```

**Code B**

```
IconButton(
        enabled = (mViewMode.playState == EPlayState.PAUSED),
        onClick = {  }
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.PlayArrow , null, modifier = iconModifier, tint = Color.Blue )
    }
```

**Added Content:**

To Gabriele Mariotti: Thanks!

The Code D works well based your way, I don't know why *Icon* always displays blue color in Code C, could you tell me? and how does `LocalContentAlpha.current` launch ?

**Code C**

```
    val iconBasedEnabled = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)

    IconButton(
        enabled = (mViewMode.playState == EPlayState.PLAYING) || (mViewMode.playState == EPlayState.PAUSED),
        onClick = { mViewMode.stopRecord()  }
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.StopCircle , null,  tint = iconBasedEnabled )
    }
```

**Code D**

```
   IconButton(
        enabled = (mViewMode.playState == EPlayState.PLAYING) || (mViewMode.playState == EPlayState.PAUSED),
        onClick = { mViewMode.stopRecord()  }
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.StopCircle , null,  tint = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current) )
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply **`alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current`** to the color used in the `tint` attribute:

```
Icon(
     Icons.Filled.PlayArrow, null,
     tint = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW move `val iconBasedEnabled  = ...` inside the `IconButton` content.

Comment: Thanks!  Move `val iconBasedEnabled  = ...`  inside the IconButton content is same as your code, but why doesn't `val iconBasedEnabled  = ...`  outside the IconButton work?

Comment: @HelloCW because of recomposition. It is not so simple to explain it in a comment. Try to start here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Another option for setting disabled alpha is using `ContentAlpha.disabled` for setting tint. Or gray color you can simply use `Color.LightGray` instead of `Color.Blue.copy(ContentAlpha.disabled)`

```
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

IconButton(
    enabled = enabled,
    onClick = {}
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.PlayArrow,
        null,
        tint = if(enabled) Color.Blue else Color.Blue.copy(ContentAlpha.disabled)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Material3](https://m3.material.io/) you can use the alpha of the [LocalContentColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#LocalContentColor()).

```
  IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }, enabled = isEnabled) {
      Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Edit,
        contentDescription = "Edit",
        tint =
        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant.copy(
          alpha = LocalContentColor.current.alpha
        ),
      )
    }
```

See the [official migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#emphasis-and) for more information